# Storybook 5 Sass-loader generate empty module classname

Tags: sass, storybook, sass-loader, webpack-5

I recently upgraded tom Next.js 11 and so I use the storybook `webpack5` beta as well. But when I add the `sass-loader` to the config:

```js
// .storybook/main.js


const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  core: {
    builder: "webpack5",
  },
  stories: ['../stories/*.stories.@(ts|tsx|js|jsx|mdx)'],
  addons: ['@storybook/addon-links', '@storybook/addon-essentials'],
  webpackFinal: async (config, { configType }) => {
    
    config.module.rules.push({
        test: /\.s[ac]ss$/i,
        use: [
          "style-loader",
          "css-loader",
          "sass-loader",
        ],
      },);

    return config;
  },
}
```

So when I start storybook then, the example has no className at all:

[image: no classname with scss]

And the `.index` class has not compiled by sass like it should in a module:

[image: just the default class is shown]

To see it yourself you can checkout my example [here](https://github.com/jawil003/Next_Webpack_5_Typescript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Storybook you can use the Storybook Saas Addon which works just fine.